# Multiple flush statements in PHP and Apache

Tags: php, ajax, apache, http, flush

I' am using `XMLHttpRequest 2` to get `chunked` response through it's `onprogress` event and displaying it in browser. Everything seems to work fine but I have a little confusion. Consider the following code:

```
<?php 
    echo "I' am sending ";
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    echo "content to client.";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
```

This is pretty standard `PHP` way of sending `chunked` response to client. However I was expecting to get output as two different chunks, one containing first `echo`'s result and other containing second's. But I' am getting a single combined chunk of both `echo` statements. When I put `sleep(1)` after first `flush()` then everything seems to work fine.

My question is that is there some deliberate wait on webserver side to wait for some other content before sending already received chunk or is there some thread scheduling mechanism that is forcing network layer of Apache to wait for it's turn.

#### Edit

I forgot to mention that I have disabled webserver's output buffering which means if I `flush` something from PHP it will get sent to browser.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that even though you're flushing PHP's buffer, your output is stuck in your web browser's buffer until the script finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.icemelon.com/tutorials/20/Output_While_Script_Still_Running.htm

You may be seeing browser output buffering here. Try adding:

```
for($k = 0; $k < 40000; $k++)
    echo ' ';
```

Right before you flush in order to fill up the browser's buffer and make it spit out your output.